# Como publicar um projeto Angular CLI no meu servidor?

Tags: angular, build

Tenho um projeto em Angularjs rodando localhost perfeitamente.
Estou tentando hospedar no servidor "**HOSTGATOR**" e não estou obtendo sucesso.
Estou gerando o Build com o *Angular CLI* e Hospedando o Dir "*Dist*" na "*www*". Ao tentar acessar o `index.html` ocorre os seguintes erros:

> ```
> Falha no carregamento do <script> com a fonte “http://site.com.br/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js”.<br>
> Falha no carregamento do <script> com a fonte “http://site.com.br/polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js”.<br>
> Falha no carregamento do <script> com a fonte “http://site.com.br/main.5d52293f160730f348fe.js”.
> ```

Então jogo todos os arquivos, inclusive o `index.html`, na raiz www. Assim ao acessar o `index.html` apresenta somente a pagina de boas vindas do Angular. "*Welcome to app!*"

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro verifique que quando vc der o build o seu href esta de acordo com o que vc espera. Caso seja direto do site por exemplo

```
site.com.br   ## não precisa do href
```

se vc quiser fazer algo tipo

```
site.com.br/app  ## use ng build --base-href=/app
```

Outro ponto importante e que voce tem que configurar seu servidor pra rediricionar todas as rotas para o index.html. Na documentacao tem explicando pors servidores mais populares.

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: Eduardo, muito obrigado por responder! Enviei um e-mail para meu servidor, pois ainda tenho dúvida quanto as configurações.